# Is there an easier method for solving a chinese remainder theorem problem?

Tags: number-theory

I have the following sets of equations:

$$\begin{align}x &\equiv 998\pmod {999}\\ x &\equiv 999\pmod{1000}\\
x&\equiv 1000\pmod {1001}
\end{align}$$

I tried to construct $x = b_1x_1c_1 + b_2x_2c_2 + b_3x_3c_3$

where:

$b_1 = 1000\cdot1001, b_2 = 999\cdot1001$ and $b_3 = 1000\cdot999$,

$c_1 = 998, c_2 = 999, c_3 = 1000$.

And to solve the $x_i$ solve the equation:

$b_ix_i = 1 \mod(\frac{999\cdot1000\cdot1001}{b_i})$

I eventually solved this, but was wondering if there is an easier way of doing this?

Kees

Comment: Hint: Write each equation as $x\equiv -1$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ fulfills the given constraints, then $x+1$ is a multiple of $999,1000,1001$.

Since they are consecutive numbers and $\gcd(999,1001)=\gcd(2,999)=1$, that is equivalent to $x$ being a multiple of $999\cdot 1000\cdot 1001$, i.e.:
$$ x+1\equiv 0\pmod{999\cdot 1000\cdot 1001} $$
or:
$$ x \equiv -1\pmod{999\cdot 1000\cdot 1001}.$$